# How to make permission re-apply for a logged-in user in Windows AD without making him log in again

Tags: active-directory

I am remotely removing a user U from a Group G.
But I have to log off and log on the user U to ensure that permissions for Group G do not apply any more to User U.

This is on a Windows 2008 server.

Is there a way to force the entire exercise of calculating permissions (which is done when a user logs in) while the user is logged in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can purge the Kerberos TGT (and all your service tickets) using something like klist purge. I don't know what APIs to call to do this programmatically.

This will just refresh the groups (and rights) in your token when you access remote resources, though.

Comment: Klist is part of Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools ? In case of @django problem it add to be run on user computer ? Is it possible to remote execute it from the server to user computer using PSTOOLS ?

Comment: In 2003 yes it was a reskit tool, 2008+ it ships in box. I wouldn't really want to call it from an app so much as find out what API it calls and just do it myself.

Comment: Ok Brian, but my question was more : Add it to be run on the client computer ?

Comment: Yes this would have to be run locally on the machine the user is logged in to. Keep in mind Kerb tickets have a lifetime of 10 hours by default, so, within a relatively short period of time these changes will get picked up.

Comment: Thanks, Do you know if there is a WMI class to do that ?

Comment: Never seen such a thing. I can't say I've actually ever seen someone want to programmatically do this in this sort of context.

Comment: In fact Klist sources are in the SDK. I add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The list of groups SIDs a user belongs to is computed in the user token, which is inserted in his processes, so in my opinion, you need the logoff/logon.

---

You can find the source of Klist.exe discribed by @Brian Desmond in the Windows Platform SDK (the API in us is `LsaCallAuthenticationPackage`)

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Samples\security\authorization\klist
```

Comment: Thank you JPBlanc. Is there any other way to give temporary permission to user (say registry edit) so that I can revoke the permission without making him logoff and on